# Eclipse - replace in files with macro? (for employing trial/full versions in Android)

Tags: eclipse, macros

I am using the simple replace in file function to convert my project to trial/full version before compiling... (just replacing the package name in all *.java and *.xml files)

That works like a charm.

Is there a simple way, to create a macro or so, that first calls a specific replace call and afterwards calls the build routine?

Comment: What technologies do you use to build your project?

Comment: eclipse internal build (ADT Plugin)... I know, ant would offer some technics, but ant would be new to me... and my solution is, even if done by hand, really fast...